# Google Drive Authentication is going to be expired on April 2016 - iOS

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth

**Google Drive Login and Sharing** 
I have implemented google drive login and sharing with the help of google Example which is given on their official website : https://github.com/googledrive/ios-quickeditor

But after login its showing "this authorization request will be expired on 20 Apr 2017" :
[image]

Please provide me alternate solution of this.

I have also created project with new Auth of google but could not able to get code of sharing PDF file with that Auth classes.

Comment: probably related to https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html   nice that they have added a note.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks! i have also implemented this one and able to login with this but still don't have any idea to share file with this authentication type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GIDSignIn request.Have solved my problems.

Also went to official: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in and implemented to my Project.Then used scope for GoogleDrive and that way received access to my Google Drive.

As far as I understand GIDSignIn uses singleton to get access to Google services.  that you doesn't need to implement OAuth 2.0 by hands any more.